# How can I incorporate Excel Array formula in Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, array-formulas

I need some help in setting up my conditional formatting. Any help or feedbacks will be greatly appreciated! This is my scenario:

There is a table named **WkdayPHols** where it contains a specific holiday to a respective date.

[image]

On another sheet within the same workbook, I need to highlight the specific cell with this condition using conditional formatting:

- If there is a matching state (in Column C), with a matching Date (Row 7), indicate that cell as 1 - as shown
- Row 9 **Yellow cell** example - Cell **C9** = VIC, Cell **D7** = Date Value 43405 - no match, therefore #N/A
- **Green cell** example, Date Value 43410 is found to be a holiday in **WkdayPHols**, any rows with Vic in Column C will have 1.

I have achieved that by using the array formula - as shown in the formula bar. However, I only want this condition to be presented as part of conditional formatting, by highlighting the specific cell with the given criteria (=1). But array formulas is not supported in conditional formatting.

I need the all the cells to be blank, without formulas for actual inputs.

Any solution/suggestion?

[image]

Comment: try using `=SUMPRODUCT(<formula>)`...

Comment: @Rosetta I tried using that and it didn't work, value=1 only appears if it is in an array form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formula in the cells to,

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 7, WkdayPHols[column1]/((WkdayPHols[dates]=I$7)*(WkdayPHols[state]=$C9)), 1), TEXT(,))
```

Use Fill Right and Fill Down, do not drag that formula into adjacent cells or the table columns will shift.

Change the cells' format to a custom number format of,

```
;;;
```

Create a conditional formattting rule based on,

```
=isnumber(d9)
```

Comment: Excellent @Jeeped This works! Because I need my cells to remain as blank, I just used your formula into my conditional formatting condition, and I got what I need.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!